# Multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin with FPDF on PHP

Tags: php, pdf, header, fpdf

I am using FPDF (http://www.fpdf.org/) to create a pdf file in PHP.

I use Laravel, and PHP 7.2.
My problem is weird, i add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" to my http header to show pdf on browser:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$pdf->Output('I')
```

When my pdf is on version 1.4 it's ok, the file is show on browser. But when my pdf is on version 1.3, the Output function of FPDF add an another 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'.

With 2 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *', the pdf is not show on browser.

**Where do you think the problem is coming from?**

I have thing of 2 solution, but it's ugly:

- Modify FPDF library to check the version, and add a Access-Control-Allow-Origin just to version 1.4
- Add empty picture to force the pdf go to version 1.4 (version 1.3 doesn't support picture)

Thanks you !

Comment: What you say makes no sense. "version 1.3 doesn't support picture" what is that supposed to mean? And `Output('I')` returns just an empty string, so why do you call it with response()?

Comment: When i add a picture with FPDF, my file is on version 1.4. So i think to had a empty picture, to force pdf on version 1.4. And Output('I') : "Send the document to a given destination: browser, file or string."" I: send the file inline to the browser. The PDF viewer is used if available."

Comment: If you use a PNG with alpha channel, yes, the PDF version is increased. Otherwise it's not. And `Output('I')` sends the PDF to the browser and returns `''` as the result of the function call.